# Comparing data in an Azure Index to data that is about to be uploaded

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cognitive-search

I have an index using the Azure Cognitive Search service. I'm writing a program to automate the upload of new data to this index. I don't want to delete and re-create the index from scratch unnecessarily each time. Is there a way of comparing what is currently in the index with the data that I am about to upload, without having to download that data from there first and manually compare it? I have been looking at the MS documentation and other articles but cannot see a way to do this comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use MergeOrUpload operation, so if it's not there it will insert, otherwise update.

Please make sure the IDs are the same otherwise you'll endup always adding new items.

```
IndexAction.MergeOrUpload(
    new Customer()
    {
        Id = "....",
        UpdatedBy = new 
        {
            Id = "..."
        }
    }
)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.indexactiontype?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Thank you @ThiagoCustodio - do you know if that will also deal with data that has been deleted. I.e. the data I want to upload is mostly the same but with a few deleted entries?